# What is the term like 'row' or 'column' for all z-coords that share the same x/y-coords?

Tags: naming

What is the term for all z coordinates that share the same x and y coordinates (eg, all x coordinates that share the same y coordinate is a "row")?

I think I will go with "hill", per this discussion: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180916073613/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52563.html)

Comment: How can z ordinates "share" x and y co-ordinates? Z ordinates don't _have_ co-ordinates. They are a number. Also at best this belongs on math.se but I think you'd have to flesh it out and be a _lot_ more clear & correct with your terminology (what is a "Z co-ordinate" or a "X co-ordinate" or a "Y co-ordinate"?)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in 3D structures you not only have individual lines of "cells", but also entire planes.

I wouldn't really transfer the row/column naming to 3D, but instead talk about planes `x=...`, `y=...` or `z=...` and lines `x=...,y=...`, `x=...,z=...` or `y=...,z=...`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with "depth" as the the term for all z coordinates that share the same x and y coordinates.